# Mysql permission issue

Tags: mysql

I am migrating a number of sites from a server running MySQL 6.0.11-alpha to a server running the CentOS MySQL 5.0.95 Source distribution.

Most of the sites worked seamlessly.  One of the sites presented a database connection error and upon investigation, I found that the user does not have access to the database as it should, and as other sites' MySQL users do.

I tried resetting the MySQL user's password (with PASSWORD and OLD_PASSWORD), tried re-issuing the GRANT statement, tried dropping and re-importing the database, all to no avail.  I tested GRANT'ing this user permission access to another database and the user was able to see that database without a problem.  This verified my GRANT syntax and the user's password.  But something must be different about the particular database preventing the user from seeing it, perhaps something with character sets?  Thank you in advance for suggestions to debug this.

Comment: Did you run mysql_upgrade? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-upgrade.html.  Stupid question, but you did flush privileges right?

Comment: thanks, i hadn't thought to run mysql_upgrade and after doing so, the user can connect to mysql from cmd line, but still not from wordpress.  going to check the wordpress forums next.